# Calculating total return with compound interest

Tags: c++, math

So, I'm trying to figure out the total amount of return from an investment of £5 with a daily interest rate of 1.01%. Obviously, I am wanting the compound interest rate, so I have this so far:

```
int main() {

    double i = 500;
    int loop;
    int loopa;
    double lowInterest;
    double highInterest;

    lowInterest = 1.01;
    highInterest = 1.75;

    cout.precision(2);

        for(loop = 1;loop < 1826;loop++) {
            if(i<1001) {
                i = i + ((i / 100) * lowInterest);
            }
            else {
                i = i + ((i / 100) * highInterest);
            }
        }

    cout << fixed << i << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I am using 500 to represent the $5 just for personal preference. Am I doing this correctly? I get very strange results - 46592024576.00 for example - that make me think that somewhere I've made an error?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to show the equation you are trying to implement, I expect your equation may be incorrect.

Comment: Essentially, I'm doing: `i = i + 1.01%` for each day in five years (1826, including a leap year). Perhaps it's a bad habit from Pascal (which is what I've done nearly all of my programming in) which doesn't accept % as 'percent'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The figure is about right - if you really were lucky enough to invest $5 at a *daily* interest rate of 1.01%, you'd end up with close to half a billion dollars after 5 years (a daily interest rate of 1.01% is an annual interest rate of ~ 3800%).

Are you sure you don't mean a daily interest rate of (1.01 / 365) % ?

Comment: Thanks caf. Seems that it is right. I couldn't believe the figure when I saw it. Now to see how much of a scam it is! :) Was calculating for a friend is all.

Comment: Maybe it's an investment denominated in Zimbabwean dollars.

Comment: Ha ha! No, wikipedia says that at some point the Zimbabwean dollar had an inflation around 10000000% (ten millions percent, and even more). Even that interest rate wouldn't have been sufficient...

Answer (score 3):

I think you are doing manually what can be done with a simple equation.

http://qrc.depaul.edu/StudyGuide2009/Notes/Savings%20Accounts/Compound%20Interest.htm

```
A = P(1 + r/n) ^ nt
```

In this case

```
p = 5 (amount you invested)
r = 0.0101*365 (annual interest rate)
n = 365 (times compounded/yr)
t = 1  (number of years)
```

So, just implement the equation.

I may be off on the value of `r` as it has been years since I took Engineering Economics and I couldn't see how many years so I guessed one.

Comment: Thanks for the forumla, James. I'll keep that for future use.

Answer (score 1):

On a tangential note, your counter `loop` should start at 0 instead of 1, otherwise it will loop 1825 times instead of 1826.